# Android default browser doesn't download a .txt file from PC localhost

Tags: php, android, browser

I wrote a script on PHP running on Wamp Server, which forces a download of a .txt file. The script looks as follows:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$newfile = "data.txt";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($newfile));   
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($newfile));
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
$fp = fopen($newfile, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
} 
fclose($fp);
```

This code is working well.

But the problem is, I've connected my Android device to PC, and able to download this file by using any other browsers, but NOT Android Default Web Browser.

Does anybody know why the download fails on the default browser? But can be downloaded from other on Android?

Answer (score 0):

The Android browser is really picky about the HTTP headers for some reason.

This page will give you some insight about the matter: http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/

To quote part of the page, if you use this line of code, it probably won't work.

`Content-Type: application/force-download`

The page also gives you some possible solutions.